# Symfony console command behat test

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, behat, symfony-console

I have command and this command connect to google analytics API and gets some data. This works but I try to wrote a test and don't know how to simulate google API connection. My first idea was to mock google API in context but how to inject this mock to command?

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 * @param InputInterface $input
 * @param OutputInterface $output
 */
public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): void
{
    //connect to google service
    /** @var $googleClient \Google_Client*/
    $googleClient = $this->googleConnect();

    /** @var $shopTokenEntity TokenEntity */
    foreach ($tokensDataProvider as $shopTokenEntity) {

        //refresh token if necessary
        $this->refreshToken($googleClient, $shopTokenEntity);

        $clientGA = new AnalyticsConversion($googleClient);
        /** @var $analytics \Google_Service_Analytics*/
        $analytics = $clientGA->getAnalyticsService();

        try {
            //do some other staff get data and save to db

        } catch (\Google_Service_Exception $err) {
            $this->getLogger()->addWarning($err->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

 /**
 *
 * @return \Google_Client
 */
private function googleConnect(): \Google_Client
{
    /** @var $conversionApp ClientConversionFactory */
    $conversionApp = $this->container->get('google.client_conversion.factory');
    /** @var $googleClient \Google_Client */
    $googleClient = $conversionApp->connect();

    return $googleClient;
}

/**
 * @param \Google_Client $googleClient
 * @param TokenEntity $tokenEntity
 */
private function refreshToken(\Google_Client $googleClient, TokenEntity $tokenEntity): void
{
    //set Auth
    $googleClient->setAccessToken($tokenEntity->getAccessToken());
    //refresh and save token if needed
    if ($googleClient->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $this->getLogger()->addInfo("Refresh token for ShopID: " . $tokenEntity->getShopId());
        $googleClient->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken();
        //save token to db
    }
}
```

My second idea was to add EventListener and change method when I connect to google service to specific event dispatcher and mock this event. Any idea will be very helpful.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, when you run your test, you have access to it's container, so you can try to insert your mock class in test, for example:
$client = static::createClient();
$client->getContainer()->set('google.client_conversion.factory', YourFactoryClass);

Comment: Yes you have right. Right now I developing something similar but I create special service_test.yml with mocked classes with I want to replace:
services:
    google.client_conversion.factory:
        class: ClientConversionFactoryMock
        arguments: ['%root_dir%/config/key/conversion_app.json']

Comment: [Mocking external APIs with behat in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/2blk/mocking-external-apis-with-behat-in-symfony) and [Mocking internal or external service or api calls with behat](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/2y8u/mocking-internal-or-external-service-or-api-calls-with-behat) would be helpful in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use someting like this:

```
    $client = static::createClient();

    $ldap = $this->getMockBuilder('AppBundle\Services\Security\LdapManager')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $client->getContainer()->set('app.ldap', $ldap);
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/');
```

Comment: Oh, great, you just copied my answer from comment above, and give it like solution.